# Social icons table keeps adding margin

Tags: html, css, mailing

I'm making a mailing html page and my social buttons keep having some kind of margin that I can't work away. I posted my code and a fiddle below so you can see where I'm stuck.

https://jsfiddle.net/zh78uc9s/

CODE:

```
<td rowspan="10" style="text-align: left" valign="top" width="auto" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <!--Social media knopkes en links-->
                    <table width="25px" height="100px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="25" height="25"><img src="elementen/Spacer25.gif" width="25" height="25" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" alt="spacerke" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="25" height="25">
                                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/GyprocBelgium/"><img src="elementen/facebook.gif" width="25" height="25" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" alt="facebook" /></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="25" height="25">
                                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/SGGyprocBelgium"><img src="elementen/youtube.gif" width="25" height="25" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" alt="youtube" /></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="25" height="25">
                                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/saint-gobain-construction-products-belgium-division-gyproc"><img src="elementen/linkedin.gif" width="25" height="25" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" alt="linkedin" /></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="25" height="25">
                                    <a href="https://twitter.com/GyprocBE"><img src="elementen/twitter.gif" width="25" height="25" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" alt="twitter" /></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin between each social buttons seams a `td`'s style setting, try with

```
td { 
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zh78uc9s/6/)